# Does onPrepareOptionsMenu work together with ContextMenu?

Tags: android

I'm using `onCreateContextMenu` to disable one of the menu items and than I also use `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to enable the menu item. But for some reason the `onPrepareOptionMenu` never launch by the system. I'm running my code in version 2.3. Since it's not working I'm wonder if `onPrepareOptionsMenu` work together with ContextMenu?

What could be wrong? Help is preciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(OptionsMenu != ContextMenu)`

onPrepareOptions menu was introduced on 3.0 because the menu from the action bar is created only once (during ActionBar creation) and it is only "prepared" right before opening it.

For context you should be using only `onCreateContextMenu`

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how I can enable/disable menu items in a context menu during runtime?

Comment: I reckon onCreateContextMenu is called every time the menu is going to be open (on that instance you can enable/disable individual menu items. To completely disable the context you can call unregisterContextMenu (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#unregisterForContextMenu(android.view.View))

Comment: OK, I thought onCreateContextMenu only called once!? But now I added a if statement inside the method to check a boolean value and that works